# $X$ and $Y$ are sets. Prove $X = \emptyset$ iff $Y = (X \cap Y^c) \cup (X^c \cap Y)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I keep on hitting a road block in trying to solve this, especially when trying to prove it going from the right hand side to the left hand side.

Comment: Why dont' you draw a picture?

Answer (score 1):

*Proof*.

$(\Rightarrow).$
Assume that $X=\varnothing$ and that $y\in Y$, evidently $y\not\in X$ therefore $y\in Y\backslash X$ consequently $y\in (Y\backslash X)\cup (X\backslash Y)$, since $y$ was arbitrary we may now conclude that $Y\subseteq (Y\backslash X)\cup (X\backslash Y)$.

Assume now that $z\in(Y\backslash X)\cup (X\backslash Y)$, evidently $X\backslash Y = \varnothing$ thus $z\in(Y\backslash X)$ consqeuently $z\in Y$.
Since our choice of $z$ was arbitrary it follows that $(Y\backslash X)\cup (X\backslash Y)\subseteq Y$.

We may now conclude that $Y = (Y\backslash X)\cup (X\backslash Y)$.

$(\Leftarrow).$ Assume for purpose of contradiction that $Y=(Y\backslash X)\cup (X\backslash Y)$ and that $X\neq\varnothing$,evidently some $x\in X$, moreover $x\in Y\lor x\not\in Y$, arguing from Cases.

*Case:-1$(x\in Y)$:* Assume $x\in Y$, since $Y = (Y\backslash X)\cup (X\backslash Y)$ it follows $x\in (Y\backslash X)\cup (X\backslash Y)$  and therefore $x\not\in X\cap Y$ but it is clearly evident that $x\in X\cap Y$ resulting in a contradiction.

*Case:-2$(x\not\in Y)$:* Assume $x\not\in Y$, since $Y = (Y\backslash X)\cup (X\backslash Y)$ it follows $x\not\in (Y\backslash X)\cup (X\backslash Y)$ but clearly $x\in X\backslash Y$ and therefore $x\in(Y\backslash X)\cup (X\backslash Y)$ again resulting in a contradiction.

Therefore it must be that $X=\varnothing$.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X=\emptyset$; then the RHS is $\emptyset \cup Y$.

Suppose $X \not = \emptyset$; then say $x \in X$. Then two mutually exclusive cases:

- $x \in Y^c$. Then we have $x \in (X \cap Y^c) \cup (X^c \cap Y)$, but $x \in Y^c$ also implies $x \not \in Y$ so $Y$ can't be equal to $(X \cap Y^c) \cup (X^c \cap Y)$.
- $x \in Y$. Then $x \not \in Y^c$ so $x \not \in X \cap Y^c$; and $x \not \in X^c$ so $x \not \in X^c \cap Y$; so $x \not \in (X \cap Y^c) \cup (X^c \cap Y)$. But $x \in Y$, so $y \not = (X \cap Y^c) \cup (X^c \cap Y)$.

Comment: Thanks. But, this is using the assumption X = { } to arrive at RHS. My main problem however is showing Y = (X n Y^c) U (X^c n Y) implies X = { }. I probably wasn't clear about that in the description.

Comment: @peakyblinders I showed both directions. The two bits starting "suppose" are the two directions.

Comment: Ahh, you are right, I see your point now. I understood the explanation except for the first case where x is an element of Y^c. I am having a hard time understanding the transition, so please tell me if my explanation is correct. Since we are assuming x is an element of Y^c, then x is an element of (X n Y^c) U (X^c n Y) holds, but this also means x is NOT an element of Y. And going from RHS to LHS, we had shown x IS an element of Y, so this is where the contradiction lies?

Answer (score 0):

$ X,Y \subset T$.

$X = \emptyset  \iff $

$Y = ( X \cap Y^C ) \cup ( X^C \cap Y )$.

1) $\Rightarrow$ :

Let $X = \emptyset$ .

$( X \cap Y^C ) \cup ( X^C \cap Y)$ =

$\emptyset \cup ( T  \cap Y) = Y$.

2) $\Leftarrow$ :

Let $Y = ( X \cap Y^C ) \cup ( X^C \cap Y)$.

$A := ( X \cap Y^C) ; B : = ( X^C \cap Y)$.

$Y = A \cup B$.

1) $A \subset Y$;

It follows that $A = \emptyset$, since every element of $A$ is an element of $Y^C$.

( Note: $Y \cap Y^C = \emptyset$ ).

$A = (X \cap Y^C) = \emptyset$,

$(\star) \rightarrow X \subset Y$.

We are left with:

$Y = X^C \cap Y$, or

$Y^C = X \cup Y^C$,

$(\star \star) \rightarrow X \subset  Y^C$.

Putting together:

$X\subset Y$ and $X\subset Y^C $

$ \rightarrow  X = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

From right to left:

$$X=$$

$$(X \cap Y) \cup (X \cap Y^C)=$$

$$(X \cap ((X \cap Y^C) \cup (X^C \cap Y))) \cup (X \cap Y^C)=$$

$$((X \cap X \cap Y^C) \cup (X \cap X^C \cap Y)) \cup (X \cap Y^C)=$$

$$((X \cap Y^C) \cup \emptyset) \cup (X \cap Y^C)=$$

$$(X \cap Y^C) \cup (X \cap Y^C)=$$

$$X \cap Y^C=$$

$$X \cap Y^C \cap Y^C=$$

$$X \cap Y^C \cap ((X \cap Y^C) \cup ( X^C \cap Y))^C =$$

$$(X \cap Y^C) \cap (X \cap Y^C)^C \cap (X^C \cap Y)^C =$$

$$\emptyset \cap (X^C \cap Y)=$$

$$\emptyset$$